# JavaScript - HTML - Issues With Textarea Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

```js
let fruits = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Strawberry'}
]




let add_to_note_box = []
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
let noteList = document.querySelector('#noteList')
let createTextBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.create-text-box')
let copyTextBtn = document.querySelector('.copy-text')


function addItems(){
  let fruitItem = ''
  let position = 'beforeend'

  for(let fruit of fruits){

    fruitItem = `<li id='${fruit.id}' class="item">
        <p id="${fruit.id}" class="fruits">${fruit.name}</p>
    </li>`

    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, fruitItem)
  }
}



list.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  //add_to_note_box.push()
  let materialSelected = event.target.classList.value
  if(materialSelected === 'fruits'){
      add_to_note_box.push(fruits[event.target.id].name)
      
    }
  if(event.target.style.backgroundColor === ""){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3498DB'
  }else{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = null
  }

})


createTextBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(add_to_note_box.length === 0){
    alert('Nothing to add to the notebox')
  }else{
    let items = ''


    for(let text of add_to_note_box){

noteList.textContent = text
    }

    add_to_note_box = []
  }
})

copyTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  if(!noteList.textContent){
    alert('There is nothing to copy')
  }else{
    noteList.select()
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyTextBtn.textContent = "Copied!"
    setTimeout(()=>{
    copyTextBtn.textContent = 'Copy Text'
  }, 2000)
  }


})



addItems()
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.parent-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  max-height: 5400px;
}

.create_notbox_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}


.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

.content ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 35px);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DBDF;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEDEF;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

.item:hover{
  background-color: #EAECEE
}


.item p{
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.create-text-box{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



/*For note box*/
/*------------------------notbox container-----------------------*/
.notebox-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}


/*--------------------------header-----------------------*/
.notebox-container .header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}

/*---------------------------content------------------------*/

.notebox-container .content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#noteList
{
  resize: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font: serif;
    color: #28B463;
    text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: none;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  width: 100%;
}


.notebox-container .content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------------Create Text Box--------------------------*/
.notebox-container .copy-text{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent-container">

<!---Select items------>
    <div class="create_notbox_container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <ul class="list" id="list">
          </ul>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="create-text-box">Create Text Box</button>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Display notebox-->
    <div class="notebox-container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <textarea class="list" id="noteList"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="copy-text">Copy Text</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to loop through my fruits array and past the fruits into the `textarea`field in the following format:

```
Fruits
  Apple
  Orange
  Banana
  Strawberry
```

However, there are couple problems that need to be addressed:

```
1.) Not all the fruits are being display in the textarea as the code loops through the fruits array.
2.) When copy text button is clicked, the border of the textarea turns black. I dont want that. 
3.) Also, how can I prevent user from deleting the text directly in the textarea field. I only want the textarea field to display the text and be able to be copied. I tried disabling the textarea but that prevents the text from being copied.
4.) The text color is set as green but when I copy and paste it into word document, the text color is black. Why didnt the green font color transfer through when I copied it?
5.) How can I copy and paste the text in the format I mentioned above with fruit names being indented?
```

```
***JAVASCRIPT***
let fruits = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Strawberry'}
]




let add_to_note_box = []
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
let noteList = document.querySelector('#noteList')
let createTextBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.create-text-box')
let copyTextBtn = document.querySelector('.copy-text')


function addItems(){
  let fruitItem = ''
  let position = 'beforeend'

  for(let fruit of fruits){

    fruitItem = `<li id='${fruit.id}' class="item">
        <p id="${fruit.id}" class="fruits">${fruit.name}</p>
    </li>`

    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, fruitItem)
  }
}



list.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  //add_to_note_box.push()
  let materialSelected = event.target.classList.value
  if(materialSelected === 'fruits'){
      add_to_note_box.push(fruits[event.target.id].name)
      console.log(add_to_note_box)
    }
  if(event.target.style.backgroundColor === ""){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3498DB'
  }else{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = null
  }

})


createTextBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(add_to_note_box.length === 0){
    alert('Nothing to add to the notebox')
  }else{
    let items = ''


    for(let text of add_to_note_box){

noteList.textContent = text
    }

    add_to_note_box = []
  }
})

copyTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  if(!noteList.textContent){
    alert('There is nothing to copy')
  }else{
    noteList.select()
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyTextBtn.textContent = "Copied!"
    setTimeout(()=>{
    copyTextBtn.textContent = 'Copy Text'
  }, 2000)
  }


})



addItems()
```

```
***CSS***
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.parent-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  max-height: 5400px;
}

.create_notbox_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}


.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

.content ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 35px);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DBDF;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEDEF;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

.item:hover{
  background-color: #EAECEE
}


.item p{
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.create-text-box{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



/*For note box*/
/*------------------------notbox container-----------------------*/
.notebox-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}


/*--------------------------header-----------------------*/
.notebox-container .header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}

/*---------------------------content------------------------*/

.notebox-container .content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#noteList
{
  resize: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font: serif;
    color: #28B463;
    text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: none;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  width: 100%;
}


.notebox-container .content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------------Create Text Box--------------------------*/
.notebox-container .copy-text{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



let fruits = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Strawberry'}
]




let add_to_note_box = []
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
let noteList = document.querySelector('#noteList')
let createTextBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.create-text-box')
let copyTextBtn = document.querySelector('.copy-text')


function addItems(){
  let fruitItem = ''
  let position = 'beforeend'

  for(let fruit of fruits){

    fruitItem = `<li id='${fruit.id}' class="item">
        <p id="${fruit.id}" class="fruits">${fruit.name}</p>
    </li>`

    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, fruitItem)
  }
}



list.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  //add_to_note_box.push()
  let materialSelected = event.target.classList.value
  if(materialSelected === 'fruits'){
      add_to_note_box.push(fruits[event.target.id].name)
      console.log(add_to_note_box)
    }
  if(event.target.style.backgroundColor === ""){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3498DB'
  }else{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = null
  }

})


createTextBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(add_to_note_box.length === 0){
    alert('Nothing to add to the notebox')
  }else{
    let items = ''


    for(let text of add_to_note_box){

noteList.textContent = text
    }

    add_to_note_box = []
  }
})

copyTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  if(!noteList.textContent){
    alert('There is nothing to copy')
  }else{
    noteList.select()
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyTextBtn.textContent = "Copied!"
    setTimeout(()=>{
    copyTextBtn.textContent = 'Copy Text'
  }, 2000)
  }


})



addItems()
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.parent-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  max-height: 5400px;
}

.create_notbox_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}


.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

.content ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 35px);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DBDF;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEDEF;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

.item:hover{
  background-color: #EAECEE
}


.item p{
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.create-text-box{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



/*For note box*/
/*------------------------notbox container-----------------------*/
.notebox-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}


/*--------------------------header-----------------------*/
.notebox-container .header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}

/*---------------------------content------------------------*/

.notebox-container .content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#noteList
{
  resize: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font: serif;
    color: #28B463;
    text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: none;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  width: 100%;
}


.notebox-container .content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------------Create Text Box--------------------------*/
.notebox-container .copy-text{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent-container">

<!---Select items------>
    <div class="create_notbox_container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <ul class="list" id="list">
          </ul>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="create-text-box">Create Text Box</button>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Display notebox-->
    <div class="notebox-container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <textarea class="list" id="noteList"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="copy-text">Copy Text</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
***HTML***
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent-container">

<!---Select items------>
    <div class="create_notbox_container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <ul class="list" id="list">
          </ul>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="create-text-box">Create Text Box</button>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Display notebox-->
    <div class="notebox-container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <textarea class="list" id="noteList"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="copy-text">Copy Text</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code in snippet below. And above i explain some points.

1 point) The reason is that you inappropriate process event click on li object. We should add and remove also elements in array `add_to_note_box` Like this

```
      if(event.target.style.backgroundColor === ""){ //add
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3498DB'
        add_to_note_box.push(fruits[event.target.id].name)
      }else{ //remove
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = null
        var index = add_to_note_box.indexOf(fruits[event.target.id].name);
        if (index !== -1) {
          add_to_note_box.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
```

Also you should add text to textarea using sign '+=' not '=' and add sign '\n' before text like this:

```
    for(let text of add_to_note_box){ // notice i use += sign and also check is this line first than i dont use \n
       
      if (noteList.textContent == "") { noteList.textContent += text; continue; }
      
      noteList.textContent += '\n'+text
    }
```

3 point) You should add attribute `disabled` to `textarea` like this

```
<textarea class="list" id="noteList" disabled></textarea>
```

```js
let fruits = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Strawberry'}
]




let add_to_note_box = []
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
let noteList = document.querySelector('#noteList')
let createTextBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.create-text-box')
let copyTextBtn = document.querySelector('.copy-text')


function addItems(){
  let fruitItem = ''
  let position = 'beforeend'

  for(let fruit of fruits){

    fruitItem = `<li id='${fruit.id}' class="item">
        <p id="${fruit.id}" class="fruits">${fruit.name}</p>
    </li>`

    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, fruitItem)
  }
}



list.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  //add_to_note_box.push()
  let materialSelected = event.target.classList.value
  if(materialSelected === 'fruits'){
      
      if(event.target.style.backgroundColor === ""){
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3498DB'
        
        add_to_note_box.push(fruits[event.target.id].name)
      }else{
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = null
        
        var index = add_to_note_box.indexOf(fruits[event.target.id].name);
        if (index !== -1) {
          add_to_note_box.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
})


createTextBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(add_to_note_box.length === 0){
    alert('Nothing to add to the notebox')
  }else{
    let items = ''
    

    for(let text of add_to_note_box){
       
      if (noteList.textContent == "") { noteList.textContent += text; continue; }
      
      noteList.textContent += '\n'+text
    }
    
    let children = list.children
    for(let child of children){
      child.querySelector("p").style.backgroundColor = null;
    }

    add_to_note_box = []
  }
})

copyTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  if(!noteList.textContent){
    alert('There is nothing to copy')
  }else{
    noteList.select()
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyTextBtn.textContent = "Copied!"
    setTimeout(()=>{
    copyTextBtn.textContent = 'Copy Text'
  }, 2000)
  }


})



addItems()
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.parent-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  max-height: 5400px;
}

.create_notbox_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}


.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

.content ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 35px);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DBDF;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEDEF;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

.item:hover{
  background-color: #EAECEE
}


.item p{
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.create-text-box{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



/*For note box*/
/*------------------------notbox container-----------------------*/
.notebox-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}


/*--------------------------header-----------------------*/
.notebox-container .header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}

/*---------------------------content------------------------*/

.notebox-container .content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#noteList
{
  resize: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font: serif;
    color: #28B463;
    text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: none;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  width: 100%;
}


.notebox-container .content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------------Create Text Box--------------------------*/
.notebox-container .copy-text{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



let fruits = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Strawberry'}
]




let add_to_note_box = []
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
let noteList = document.querySelector('#noteList')
let createTextBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.create-text-box')
let copyTextBtn = document.querySelector('.copy-text')


function addItems(){
  let fruitItem = ''
  let position = 'beforeend'

  for(let fruit of fruits){

    fruitItem = `<li id='${fruit.id}' class="item">
        <p id="${fruit.id}" class="fruits">${fruit.name}</p>
    </li>`

    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, fruitItem)
  }
}



list.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  //add_to_note_box.push()
  let materialSelected = event.target.classList.value
  if(materialSelected === 'fruits'){
      add_to_note_box.push(fruits[event.target.id].name)
      console.log(add_to_note_box)
    }
  if(event.target.style.backgroundColor === ""){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3498DB'
  }else{
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = null
  }

})


createTextBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(add_to_note_box.length === 0){
    alert('Nothing to add to the notebox')
  }else{
    let items = ''


    for(let text of add_to_note_box){

noteList.textContent = text
    }

    add_to_note_box = []
  }
})

copyTextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  if(!noteList.textContent){
    alert('There is nothing to copy')
  }else{
    noteList.select()
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyTextBtn.textContent = "Copied!"
    setTimeout(()=>{
    copyTextBtn.textContent = 'Copy Text'
  }, 2000)
  }


})



addItems()
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.parent-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  max-height: 5400px;
}

.create_notbox_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}


.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

.content ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.items-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 35px);
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DBDF;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEDEF;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

.item:hover{
  background-color: #EAECEE
}


.item p{
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.create-text-box{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}



/*For note box*/
/*------------------------notbox container-----------------------*/
.notebox-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgb(171, 178, 185);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}


/*--------------------------header-----------------------*/
.notebox-container .header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2E86C1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;

}

/*---------------------------content------------------------*/

.notebox-container .content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 390px;
  max-height: 390px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#noteList
{
  resize: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font: serif;
    color: #28B463;
    text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: none;
  height: calc(100% - 35px);
  width: 100%;
}


.notebox-container .content::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none;
}

/*--------------------------Create Text Box--------------------------*/
.notebox-container .copy-text{
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #21618C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent-container">

<!---Select items------>
    <div class="create_notbox_container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <ul class="list" id="list">
          </ul>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="create-text-box">Create Text Box</button>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Display notebox-->
    <div class="notebox-container">
      <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <textarea class="list" id="noteList" disabled></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="copy-text">Copy Text</button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot. However, problems 3 and 4 still are not resolved. If I disable the textarea, I will not be able to copy the text. Also, the text color is green, but when I copy and paste it into notepad, the font color is black.